# python - ensure script is activated only once

Tags: python, python-2.7, atomic

I'm writing a `Python 2.7` script.
In summary, this script is being run every night on `Linux` and activates several processes.

I'd like to ensure this script is not run multiple times in parallel (basically trying to mimic `Singleton` pattern but on application level) .

***Code Example***

```
def main():
    # before doing anything, I'd like to know whether this
    # script was activated and alive. 
    # if so, error out

    # do something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

***Suggestion***

The naive solution would be to create some kind of a lock file, that acts as a mutex.
 The first thing we do is to check whether this file exists. if so, then other instance of the script already created it and we should error out. when the script is done, we remove this file.
I'm assuming this solution would work, as long as the operations on the file system are atomic.

***Implementation***

```
import os, sys

lock_file_path = ".lock_script"

def lock_mutex():
    if os.path.exists(lock_mutex_path):
        print "Error: script was already activated."
        sys.exit(-1)

    else:
        file = open(lock_mutex_path, 'w')

def unlock_mutex():
    assert( os.path.exists(lock_mutex_path))
    os.remove(lock_mutex_path)

def main():

    try:
        lock_mutex()

        # do something

        unlock_mutex()

    except:
        unlock_mutex()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

***Problem***

How to ensure `lock_mutex()` and `unlock_mutex()` are atomic?

Comment: You do not want to invoke script if it is working already right?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is the script started such that this is a concern?

Comment: I don't think your solution is a *naive* solution. In fact, it is quite common for one to create a lock file to check if the script is running.

Comment: Artur, that's right. ratatoskr, not sure if I understand, but this script was accidentally activated but couple of users. That caused a BUG the took some time to find. I'm trying to avoid such BUGs in the future.

Comment: aIKid, Let's assume my suggestion is the best that we have so far, how do you ensure the file system operation are atomic? (not suggesting you can't, I am not sure how to accomplish that)

Comment: Maybe take a look at `os.rename()`, which should be an atomic operation. Try to rename your lock file, if it fails then don't run script. Name it back when you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use supervisor (http://supervisord.org/) to run stuff under Linux. It runs Django, Celeryd and so on and ensures that they get restarted in case they finish unexpectedly.

But it's also possible to set the options so commands aren't started or restarted automatically when it finishes: autostart=false, autorestart=false, starseconds=0. I use that for these cron jobs.

In cron I put the command "supervisorctl start myscript", which does nothing if myscript is already running under supervisor, and otherwise starts it.

Works perfectly, regardless of the language that the script is written in.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're using linux, you can make use of [`flock`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock):

```py
import os
import fcntl
import time

def main():
  # acquire the prog lock
  if not prog_lock_acq('singleton.lock'):
    print("another instance is running")
    exit(1)

  print("program is running-press Ctrl+C to stop")
  while True:
    time.sleep(10)

def prog_lock_acq(lpath):
  fd = None
  try:
    fd = os.open(lpath, os.O_CREAT)
    fcntl.flock(fd, fcntl.LOCK_NB | fcntl.LOCK_EX)
    return True
  except (OSError, IOError):
    if fd: os.close(fd)
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

It doesn't matter that we left the file open after exiting the `prog_lock_acq` because when the process exits, it will be automatically closed by the OS. Also, if you leave out `LOCK_NB` option, the `flock` call will block until the current running process quits. Depending on your use case, that might be useful.

Note that we're not deleting the file on exit. It doesn't matter. Existence of the file doesn't indicate a live process—the lock does. So even if you kill your process with `kill -9`, the lock is still released.

There is however a caveat: if you unlink the lock file while the process is running, when the next instance of the process is run, it will create a new file which will have no lock on it and will run just fine which will violate our singleton design. You might be able to do something clever with a directory to prevent unlinking but I'm not sure how robust that would be.